# Is it possible to get currently shown frame of a .gif?

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

We have a situation where we have a number of (animated) .gif files. We can change the underlying .gif, but that resets the new one to start. What we would want is to have the playback continue with the new .gif (all our .gif's have the same layout/number of frames/etc.)

The first in this process would probably be something like:

**Is it possible to get currently shown frame of a .gif ?**

Answer (score 0):

Not gif. But you can do for html. the basic code be found on.

https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/04/capturing-html-5-video-to-an-image.aspx

converting GIF to mp4

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/11/gif-to-video/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <video id="video" controls="controls">
            <source src="element_stream.mp4" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        </video>

        <button id="capture">Capture</button>

        <div id="output" crossorigin></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function () {
            "use strict";

            var video, output;
            var scale = 0.25;
            output = document.querySelector("#output");
            video = document.querySelector("#video");
            document.querySelector("#capture").addEventListener('click', function () {
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = video.videoWidth * scale;
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight * scale;
                canvas.getContext('2d')
                    .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
                output.prepend(img);
            });

        }());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```